# Using \pause with graphics animation

Tags: beamer, graphics, overlays, animate, pause

How can I hide the animation in my code?. I use [this](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/ICCV98/images/angel_an.gif) image (`.gif`).

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
  \xyoption{arc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\section{section1}

\frame{\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
\begin{itemize}
  \item point1
    \pause
  \item point2
   \pause
  \item point3
   \pause
  \item point4
  \animategraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm, autoplay,loop]{1}{listefigures/shadowscanner/im}{1}{11}
    \pause
  \item point5
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no automatic tool for indenting the example code. You can use your keyboard :-) Next time just ask a new question for it (on meta obviously in this case). This information does not belong to the OP as it has nothing to do with your actual question.

Comment: This seems to be a documented bug of the [`animate` package](http://www.math.mun.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf). On p.22 of its documentation: "Animations should not be placed on multilayered slides created with presentation
making classes such as Beamer or Powerdot. Although possible (on the last
overlay of a slide, at best), the result might be disappointing. Put animations
on ﬂat slides only. (Of course, slides without animations may still have overlays.)"

Comment: @KevinC, thanks. I know that i can put animation in one slide using only command, but in this case I can not use \pause for the other slide in the same frame. It is so complicated to combine some command beamer.

Comment: If including the animated `.gif` file is an option, then you can use the `movie15` package, which supports Beamer overlays. Simply replace the `\animategraphics...` with `\includemovie{1cm}{1cm}{angel_an.gif}`. Also, you need to comment out the `multimedia` package; otherwise there will be a conflict.

Comment: @KevinC thanks a lot. It is going but the movie does not appears. it seems that my Mac pro lucks a media player.

Comment: This only works with Adobe Reader, and you'd have to download a plugin to be able to use it.

Comment: @KevinC, I know. thanks for your support. I fixed the problem by converting the .gif to .avi.

Comment: I'm glad it works out `:)`

Comment: @Kevin: Please don't advertise package `movie15`; it is outdated. Instead, package `media9` should be used.

Comment: @AlexG, Thanks Alex, I tried to use media9 but I had en error that I forgot it. For this reason, I used movie15.

Comment: @AlexG: Thanks for pointing that out. I was aware that `movie15` has become obsolete. But `media9` didn't work with `.gif` when I tried (perhaps due to my unfamiliarity with it). In any case, the OP is aware of this now. Thanks `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For insertion of `animate` generated animations into layered `beamer` frames use the following approach. It inserts a phantom box of the same size as the animation on frame overlays where the animation is to be hidden.

The original GIF was exploded into a set of PNG files `angel_an-0.png` ... `angel_an-10.png` by

```
convert  angel_an.gif angel_an.png
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\section{section1}

\frame{\frametitle{Titre de la fen\^etre}
\begin{itemize}
  \item point1
    \pause
  \item point2
   \pause
  \item point3
   \pause
  \item point4
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{beamer@anotherslide}}{
      \phantom{\rule{0.6\linewidth}{0.45\linewidth}}
    }{
      \animategraphics[width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.45\linewidth,autoplay,loop]{3.33}{angel_an-}{0}{10}
    }
    \pause
  \item point5
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is genius! Works great!